# Construction of explicit atlas on $S^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let's consider $S^n=\{(x_0,\cdots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}:x_0^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1\}$. One can check that this is an $n$-dimensional manifold using inverse function theorem, but I'd like to construct an explicit atlas on it.

Take $N=(1,0,\cdots,0)$ and $S=(-1,0,\cdots,0)$, and let $U_1=S^n\setminus \{N\}$ and $U_2=S^n\setminus \{S\}$ and define $\phi_1(x_0,\cdots,x_n)=\frac{1}{1-x_0}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $\phi_2(x_0,\cdots,x_n)=\frac{1}{1+x_0}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$.

Then the claim is that $(U_i,\phi_i)$ form compatible charts.

But I have several problems seeing this.

I can see that $\phi_i$ are bijective onto $\mathbb{R}^n$. In fact for fixed $x_0$ they map a "circle" on $S^n$ to a "circle" (or sphere?) in $\mathbb{R}^n$

It is clear that $\phi_i$ are continuous.

But here I'm stuck. My questions are

> What exactly inverses look like?
>
> If one can't find inverses explicitly (or if it is not really needed), how does one show that inverses are continuous, and the transition map is diffeomorhpic?

Comment: This is *stereographic projection*. Consider the case $n = 1$---what is the geometric meaning of $\phi_1$?

Comment: @Travis Well, you define the image of the point on $S^1$ to be the point of intersection between the real line and the line connecting the point on $S^1$ and the pole. But how does that help me?

Comment: You can use this geometric relationship to work out explicitly a formula for $\phi_1^{-1}$, as I see John Hughes has just done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverse can we found down explicitly (here for "N"):

We want to map
$$\tag1(x_1,\ldots, x_n)\mapsto (x_0,(1-x_0)x_1,\ldots, (1-x_0)x_n),$$
but need to find suitable $x_0$ that guarantees norm $1$.
That is, we want to solve
$$ x_0^2+(1-x_0)^2(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)-1=0$$
where $x_0=1$ is a trivial, but undesired solution, which we divide out:
$$ x_0+1+(x_0-1)(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)=0,$$
$$\tag2x_0=\frac{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2\;-1}{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2\;+1}. $$
Note that $x_0$ in $(2)$ and hence the right hand side of $(1)$ is a continuos function of the input.

---

If you play around with both maps, you should find that the transition map is (both ways) something like
$$ (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto \frac1{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2} (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$$

Answer (score 3):

The inverse of $\phi_1$ sends a point $P$ in the plane, to the point 
$$
Q = PN \cap S^n
$$
where $PN$ denotes the line segment from $P$ to the north pole $N$, and $Q$ is the point of the intersection that's *not* $N$.

Such a point has the form 
$$
sP + (1-s) N
$$
and has length $1$ (or squared length 1), which (since the vectors $P$ and $N$ are orthogonal) that 
$$
s^2 \|P\|^2 + (1-s)^2 = 1 \\
s^2 \|P\|^2 + (1-s)^2 = 1 \\
s^2 \|P\|^2 + s^2 - 2s  = 0 \\
s(s \|P\|^2 + s - 2)  = 0
$$
hence either $s = 0$ (which gives $Q$ = north pole) or 
$$
s(\|P|^2 + 1) = 2 \\
s = \frac{2}{\|P\|^2 + 1}.
$$
So this gives you an explicit formula:
$$
\phi^{-1}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \frac{2}{\|P\|^2 + 1} (0, x_1, \ldots, x_n) + (1 - \frac{2}{\|P\|^2 + 1)} (0, \ldots, 0, 1). 
$$

There's a decent chance I've screwed up the algebra here, but I hope you get the main idea and check the details for yourself.